# Setting environment variables in shell script OS X

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to create a Shell Script to automate my local dev environment. I need it start some processes (Redis, MongoDB, etc.), set the environment variables then start the local web server. I'm working on OS X El Capitan.

Everything is working so far, except the environment variables. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Starting the Redis Server
if pgrep "redis-server" > /dev/null
then
    printf "Redis is already running.\n"
else
    brew services start redis
fi

# Starting the Mongo Service
if pgrep "mongod" > /dev/null
then
    printf "MongoDB is already running.\n"
else
    brew services start mongodb
fi

# Starting the API Server
printf "\nStarting API Server...\n"
source path-to-file.env
pm2 start path-to-server.js --name="api" --watch --silent

# Starting the Auth Server
printf "\nStarting Auth Server...\n"
source path-to-file.env
pm2 start path-to-server.js --name="auth" --watch --silent

# Starting the Client Server
printf "\nStarting Local Client...\n"
source path-to-file.env
pm2 start path-to-server.js --name="client" --watch --silent
```

The `.env` file is using the format `export VARIABLE="value"`

The environment variables are just not being set at all. But, if I run the exact command `source path-to-file.env` before running the script then it works. I'm wondering why the command would work independently but not inside the shell script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is in that file? How does `echo $-` compare between your interactive shell where it works and the script where it doesn't?

Comment: ...the most likely scenario is that you're running `set -a` in `~/.bashrc` or similar.

Comment: (assuming reasonable expectations -- ie. that you don't expect the variables to be interactively available after the script exits).

Comment: ...btw, inspecting output of `brew services list` is a better choice than `pgrep` here -- you don't want a separate script called, say, `poll-mongod` to match `pgrep mongod`.

Comment: ...BTW, "I'm using `echo $-` in the shell to check" doesn't actually tell me anything useful. The output of `$-` doesn't reflect which variables are established, but which (of a specific subset of) shell configuration settings are active. Please provide the *exact* values given by both instances.

Comment: ...if you provided content for `path-to-file.env`, that would also be useful -- if it contains explicit `export` or `declare -x` lines, for instance, that rules out some possibilities.

Comment: If I add `echo $VARIABLE` inside the shell script, then yes the variable is set.

If I run `echo $VARIABLE` in the shell that I executed the script in, then the variable is not set.

The 3 apps that are being run with pm2 have no access to the variables that are being set.

Comment: `echo $VARIABLE` isn't a good way to tell what's set to start with. Use `declare -p`.

Comment: ...`echo $VARIABLE` will show you outright inaccurate content in a number of cases -- for instance, if `VARIABLE='*'`, it'll show you a list of files in the current directory; if it's a multi-line string, it'll get squooshed together into a single line. `echo "$VARIABLE"` is a bit better, but still has some significant faults.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I've edited the question adding the format I used in the .env file. The main concern is that the apps aren't accessing the variables that are being set.

Thanks for all the valuable tips! :)

Comment: (...and you shouldn't be using all-caps names for your own variables -- see POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: all-uppercase names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system; names with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed to be safely usable by applications without conflicting with OS-defined names. This applies to shell variables as well as environment variables because trying to assign to the former with a name already used by an environment variable will overwrite the latter).

Comment: Hmmm. Does `bash -x yourscript` show anything interesting or unexpected? (Does it show those `export`s actually happening?)

Comment: btw, there's no reason to source the file three times -- if the variables are ever set and exported, they'll apply to *all* subsequent subprocesses.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that was probably an oversight of mine when typing the question. They are 3 individual files with environment variables for each server that's being run.

My problems were fixed, however, by using `source start-local.sh` rather then `./start-local.sh`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If that's the only resolution you have thus far, there's still a problem in your script that we should be fixing. With the information you've given, this should certainly expose the environment variables set in your source'd files to the `pm2`-launched processes, even though it quite correctly won't make them interactively available unless you use `source`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the question that I asked has been answered? The script is working perfectly now.

Comment: ...but if it only works if you execute it with a preexisting interpreter (as `source` does), then you can't actually successfully *run it as a script*. You can't use `source` if you're starting it from a non-shell program like Python, for instance, or with `find -exec` or in numerous other circumstances. You've got a workaround, and that's great, but it's a workaround that has significant caveats and generally shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: ... @JuanTomas provided an excellent answer for the case where you want your "variables [to be] set in [your] interactive dev environment", but inasmuch as what you care about is not the interactive environment but the subprocesses, the workaround shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: ...so there's something else funny going on in your shell, and it'd be interesting to figure out just what that is. (Alias or shell function overriding `pm2` when run from the interactive interpreter, perhaps?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you execute a script, it executes in a subshell, and its environment settings are lost when the subshell exits.  If you want to configure your interactive shell from a script, you must `source` the script in your interactive shell.

```
$ source start-local.sh
```

Now the environment should appear in your interactive shell.  If you want that environment to be inherited by subshells, you must also `export` any variables that will be required.  So, for instance, in path-to-file.env, you'd want lines like:

```
export MY_IMPORTANT_PATH_VAR="/example/blah"
```

Comment: The OP *is* sourcing the file. I *presume* that they're checking whether the variables are set via the behavior of their `pm2` services invoked afterwards; if they intend them to be available in their outer shell, then yes, that's an obvious expectations failure.

Comment: I'm using `echo $-` in the shell to check and they're not being set. This does make sense though. Is there any way to do what I want to do without sourcing each file individually?

Comment: I see `source` invocations *within* the script.  There's no indication that the script itself has been sourced from the interactive shell.

Comment: I was running the script above with `./start-local.sh` .. I'm very new to shell scripting so I wasn't aware that it ran in a subshell.

Comment: @nickcorin, waitaminute. Which shell do you expect these variables to be set in? The one that's executing your script, or the one from which you're interactively invoking that script? I asked you to `echo $-` to see if its output included the letter `a` (which would mean that all assignments are automatically exported).

Comment: @nickcorin, ...that's not a subshell, it's just a subprocess that happens to be a shell interpreter. A subshell is what you get with `()` or a pipeline, where you have a `fork()` of an existing interpreter instance with no `execve()` call after.

Comment: @Charles, I think he wants the variables set in his interactive dev environment.  So, `$ source ./start-local.sh`.

Comment: @JuanTomas, ...as clarified, I agree with you now.

Comment: I'm wanting the variables to be accessed by the apps that are going to be run with pm2, which they are not. Everything is blank when they're run.

Comment: @nickcorin, ...ahh; so it's not about interactive access? Then that puts us back into a different line of questioning. Could you address my comments on the question itself?

Comment: Thanks :) Running the script with `source start-local.sh` instead of `./start-local` fixed all my problems.